# PDF generation from Latex output (generated by doxygen) does not output function documentation when @param is used

Tags: pdf, doxygen

I am trying to generate pdf from LaTeX. LaTeX output is generated using Doxygen. I see that the the pdf is gets generated but the function `documentation` is missing. I narrowed it down to usage of `@param`. when `@param` is not used in comments, the pdf output does show the function `documentation`.

Could someone please suggest what the issue could be? And how to get around it?

I tried using the `tabu` version from https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu but with that I am seeing another error

> missing \begin{document}

I have tried using latest versions of MikTex and TexLive.

I see advice stating that I should move back to older version of Latex but I dont find those installers anywhere. Any pointers would help.

Comment: As written by Kurt there is a problem with the tabu versions after mid of December 2018, We are waiting for a solution ... for the time being best is to downgrade to a version from before mid of December 2018. Cross posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411317/pdf-generation-from-latex-output-generated-by-doxygen-does-not-output-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W32TeX do not  generally keep older versions however TeX Live does and some others are included in the DVD ISO.

So if you are confident that an **older TeX Live** is the answer you could use the earlier 2018 iso at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Images Alternatively to download 2017 you could use http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2017/ but it is a 3.4Gb ISO or for parts there is http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final/ but that presumes you have a base 2017 system to update and will eventually take you up to the March 2018 release

If you do prefer **Older MiKTeX** without the Full ISO then the annual versions are imbedded in Protex and the historic versions will be found here ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/protext/

**For Mactex** users not wanting the Full DVD download there is a link to ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/mactex as described here http://www.tug.org/mactex/SupportedSystems.html

Some possibly older variants of **ConTeXt** can be found at http://minimals.contextgarden.net/ though according to this page you just install by specifying the date see https://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Reverting_to_an_older_installation

Comment: Using the 2017 Texlive solved the problem that i was facing with the @param.
Thank you very much.

Ideally, I will have to wait till the tabu issues are resolved and they become part of the tex releases.

Comment: glad that was it